# Definition of a joule relative to gravitational PE

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, si-units

Why was it determined to calculate as 'pushing' an object (at the same height) over 1m instead of 'dropping' an object at 1 meter.

In other words, dropping a 1kg object at 1m would have 9.8J, but pushing 1 kg object on a (frictionless) surface for 1m would have 1J. Why wasn't it done as a function of gravity, and so produce the reverse result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pushing" is a more universal concept than "dropping". While, in the presence of matter, there will always be some action of gravity, if you are anywhere else in the Universe other than on Earth, the amount of gravitational force out there will be considerably different (and may be hard to determine and, in a sense, irrelevant - c.f. an astronaut, in weightlessness: things just don't "drop", but hover where they're released.). Even on Earth, the location of gravity can vary from point to point. Hence it makes more sense to use the notion of "pushing" to define energy.

Of course, one can standardize a value to represent an "idealized" Earth gravity - and this is done: that value is $g = 9.806\ 65\ \mathrm{\frac{m}{s^2}}$ exactly. However, if you do this, you are in effect then setting a standard for force, as well - but in a system of units built this way, you now get a constant appearing in Newton's second law:

$$F = k_N ma$$

instead of

$$F = ma$$

. And the philosophy behind the International System is to make it the latter, not the former - hence the joule. That said, the British/American system of units *is* built the way that your thinking goes: mass and force, when described as being in "pounds", are actually two different things - so they're often called as "pounds of mass" and "pounds of force" (denoted lbm and lbf), respectively, when more clarity is needed. And then Newton's second law, indeed, *does* have a $k_N$ in it (Technically it does in SI, too, but its value is $1\ \mathrm{\frac{N}{kg \cdot \frac{m}{s^2}}}$, which is dimensionlessly $1$, so we can ignore it. In American, the value is approximately $\frac{1}{32.174}\ \mathrm{\frac{lbf}{lbm \cdot \frac{ft}{s^2}}}$ - at least if you measure speed in feet per second. If you use MPH, you'll have a different value still.).

(That said - an alternative way to define energy may be in terms of neither "pushing" nor "dropping", but *heating*: if you do this, you get units like the calorie (cal) and its cousin the kilocalorie (kcal) or "Calorie" which is often used to refer to the biologically available energy within foodstuffs.)

Answer (score 1):

A joule is a unit that is equivalent to a newton-metre.  That is, you multiply a force in newtons by a distance in metres and you get a quantity with units of joules.  As you point out, this means that a force of 1 newton over a distance of 1 metre produces work of 1 joule.

It would be possible to define some new unit, newjoule, as $\tfrac{1}{9.8}$ times one newton times one metre.  With this new unit, you would get work of 1 newjoule by moving an object 1 metre against the force of gravity (9.8 newtons).

But if you replaced joules with newjoules, you would then have to include $\tfrac{1}{9.8}$ as a factor in all your calculations of work, which seems a bit inconvenient.